# Excel Interop Shapes has no Item method

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am trying to get a shape by name. The shape in question is a picture. The code compiles but at runtime I get "error CS1061: 'Shapes' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'Shapes' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". However, Item() is listed in docs and intelliSense. I have noticed the same issue with the Names collection, but in that case I worked around it by looping through the collection. That's not practical in this case. What am I missing?

```
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace MyWorkbook
{
    public partial class Sheet1
    {
        private CommandButton btnDelete;

        private void btnDelete_Click()
        {
            xl.Shape S = this.Shapes.Item("Name"); 
            if (S != null) S.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.item?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Shapes_Item_System_Object_

Comment: you are missing that in C# we are accessing colletion's items with indexer

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, when I try using an indexer I get error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Shapes' and the code does not compile.

Comment: it's not a static method. You must assign to the Shapes collection by way of a Worksheet Object instance - `xl.Shape S = ws.Shapes.Item("Name");` - How you hook to the worksheet(ws), I'll leave to you...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was perhaps not clear that this is in the worksheet class, so Shapes refers to this.Shapes. In fact I think to refer to the Shapes class I would have to use xl.Shapes. Note that xl is the alias for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the using statement.